# What is a good way to compress filenames?

Tags: encoding, compression, naming-conventions

Suppose I have a descriptive filename with some agreed on naming convention, e.g:

`typ_blue_sz_00215416_st_00001_end_00138_p1_ht_p2_w_p3_wt_ts_20160707130232.h5`

In this (made up) example, the file is an HDF5 data file, and the filename is delimited by a combination of underscores and keywords. The keywords here are `typ` for "type," `sz` for "size," `st` for "start," `end`, `p1` - `p3` for "parameter 1 through 3," and `ts` stands for "timestamp." Naming the file in this way facillitates both programmatic parsing and human readability... but as the amount of metadata one wishes to convey increases, the filename approaches the OS limit (256 in the case of Windows).

We need a way to shorten these filenames substantially. We are all agreed that we do not want to depend on reading this metadata from within the file... we want it in the filename. We are willing to compromise, though, on human readibility as long as easy programmitic parsing remains.

One solution is to implement some sort of code and mapping... so that we can convey the same amount of data in less characters, provided that you have the decoder. Are there better ways? Is there some sort of standard solution to this problem? One thing that comes to mind is TinyURL, which seems to operate using the same concept.

Comment: Do all files use all keywords and in same order? If so, remove the keywords  and only have values separated by some delimiter - ie. First value is always the type, second value is always size, etc. Also use numeric constants in place of values:  1=txt, 2=jpeg, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the information in binary, the convert that to allowed filename characters using Base64 or something similar.

Let's say you have 3 bits for the color, 27 bits for the size, 17 bits for start, 17 bits for end, 8 bits for each of the three parameters (just making this up as I go along), and 32 bits for the timestamp. That's 120 bits total. Using Base64, that can be encoded into 20 characters. The result would look something like:

`rSitpmY9RX1kq6N73ML1.h5`

Comment: Does this actually shorten the file name though? Like the example i gave above, could I encode that in binary then base 64 it? I actually tried it in Python when you suggested it... converted the string to binary and then base 64, and it had more characters than I started with. Perhaps if I ensured the string was ASCII? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Um, yes. A 77 character name became 23 characters. Looks shortened to me. I don't think you're getting it. You need to figure out what information you are encoding in the name, and put _only that information_ in as few bits as possible in a string of bits. Convert that string of bits to bytes. Do a Base64 conversion.

Comment: Yes but it seems that you're implying that I truncate my string... i.e. remove the "un-needed" parts and then base 64 that. I would like something that essentially lets me do a straight conversion of my current string (which I could limit to a small subset of ASCII) to a smaller string... and then easily convert back, preferably without an additional key. I think this answer puts me on the right track though! Upvoted. :)

Comment: If you want to make something smaller, the first thing to do is take out the stuff you don't need.

Comment: If you want to convert a limited set of characters, e.g. lower case letters, digits, and underscores (37 symbols) into a string of readable ASCII characters (let's be generous and say 92), then you can get at most the ratio of the logarithms of those numbers as the compression ratio, ~0.8. So that would reduce your 77 character name to, at best, 62 characters. Hardly seems worth it.